# Decision tree- Alternative model to predict this data?

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, cart, boosting

My data looks something this (for example):

```
 V1  V2  Type  Calification
 T   T    0       0
 F   F    0       5
 T   F    2       0
 T   T    3       5
 T   F    0       3
 F   T    4       0
```

Where **V1** and **V2** take the values TRUE or FALSE, **type** takes the values of 0 to 4 and **calification** takes the value 0 to 5.

The variable that I want to predict is Type.

I was using decision trees for each type, that is, a decision tree is made only for type 0, another for type 1 and so on with the other types. So the tree with the highest predicted calification would be chosen. For example,

Suposse that the independent variables that I inserte are V1 and V2 (T, T), then In each tree the predicted calification will be as follows

```
 Tree | Predicted_Calification
 t0   |  0
 t1   |  0
 t2   |  0
 t3   |  5
 t4   |  3
```

So I choose the tree with the highest calification and thus the type, so that the predicted type would be 3.

The decision tree for the type 0, 1 ,2,4are:

[image: hello]

[image]

The firts is for type 0 and the second is for type 1,2,3.

**Is there any other model that can solve this problem without the need to create so many decision trees? I know that this problem can be easily solved with if-else, but the goal is to perform this task through a machine learning algorithm**

Comment: One tree can predict 3 categories.  Decide if you are predicting type or califorcation. You have more data than that in reality, right?  If so, see how well your model fits on a hold sample and use more traditional fit statistics like misclassification rate.

Comment: Try multinomial logistic regression, then a simple DNN with softmax activations in the output layer.

Comment: @Nw2this Yes,I hace more data. They modelo fits well, I want to find a another model that doesn't hace to create and evaluate so many trees

Comment: @SkanderH. Could you extend your idea in an answer?, please

Comment: There are a pile of models that go in the bucket as "similar to CART" but they each have strengths and weaknesses.  GLM with multinomial might work.  You could make an SVM or MLP work.